# Как я могу определить в своем приложении, что пользователь приобрел подписку Play Pass?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-billing

я хочу посчитать, сколько пользователей имеют активную подписку Play Pass. Можно ли это определить, если в моем приложении не включен Play Pass?

Я пытался получить эту информацию от BillingClient, но не получилось.